# Wolfram Mathematica show N until specific number is reached

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Can anybody who's using Wolfram Mathematica tell me how i can show N until a specific number is generated? Want to show the value of pi until it reaches 6764.

Answer (score 0):

See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PiDigits.html especially the downloadable notebook.

```
pi = N[Pi, 30000];
string = StringTake[ToString[pi], {3, -3}];
pos = StringPosition[string, "6764"][[All, 2]];
"3." <> StringTake[string, First[pos]]
```

> 3.1415926535...162788**6764**